# Visual Studio Installer wizard: Restriction on Input length

Tags: winforms, windows-installer

I am using visual studio setup projects User dialog screen.
While using VS installer and taking input from user through *Textboxes (A)* is there a way to restrict those field to a certain length ?

Comment: Do you want to apply restrictions to a `TextBox` in the Visual Studio Installer wizard? Do you apply restrictions to a `TextBox` on your form? Do you mean you are creating a setup project and want to apply limitations to a `TextBox` in the wizards that you created?

Comment: Exactly, I want Textbox to not accept more than three(3) alphabets (only). These fields will be saved in config file.

Comment: I pointed to 3 different cases. Which case do you mean exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a way to do this with Visual Studio setups. The only dialog that has any verification is the optional Customer Information dialog with a MaskedEdit control. Also there is no support for validation custom code to run in the UI sequence.

If you were to edit the MSI file (with Orca, for example), I'd look at the Control table in the MSI file, find (say) the CustomTextA dialog if you are using that added form. There'll be a control called Edit1 (typically) with a Type of Edit and your property name in the Property column. I'd change the Type to MaskedEdit and put the masked edit validation string value in the Text column. See the SerialNumberTemplate example from Customer Information - do a build including that form and with ShowSerialNumber True.  If you can figure out the MaskedEdit string for three alphas then Windows will validate it for you. That's probably the minimal change needed to get that working.

This is the MaskedEdit validation doc:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa369797(v=vs.85).aspx

and this the Control table layout:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368044(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: But it is not a long term solution, manually open the MSI and then change its properties. Even if I figure out a validation string for three alphas only, still this process will not be that helpful. Thank you but is there any other way around?

Comment: What I am suggesting is that using Orca with some kind of script? I don't have to manually open it up every time I compile my setup.

Comment: The MSI file is a database and this thread has an postbuild example : https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/c1326233-3f10-4d98-96a7-4a22e5eeaa2d/windows-installer-error-error-code-2869-msidbcustomactiontypenoimpersonate?forum=windowsgeneraldevelopmentissues  and search for --windows installer vbscript examples-